# Sybase - how can extract part of a text from a field with repetitive strings?

Tags: sybase

I have got fields like this:

```
UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>prio</name><newValue>5</newValue><oldValue>1</oldValue><newValue>aaa<oldValue>10863321</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>
UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>prio</name><newValue>51</newValue><oldValue>11</oldValue><newValue>bbb<oldValue>10863321</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>
```

and I am trying get extract text after first `<newValue>` from the left side. It will be either one or two numbers/letters. Also, at the same time I want to get first `<oldValue>` looking from left. SO the results are:

```
newValue oldValue
5        1
51       11
```

The usual mysql commands `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and `REGEXP_SUBSTR` do not work.

Please note that I need to do it without defining any variables.

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? are you saying that the entire string 'UPDATE....Changes>' is in a column in the table?  what queries have you tried so far (that are valid in your Sybase database)?

Comment: if this was a properly formatted XML string, and you are using Sybase ASE, you could probably parse the output via the `xmltable()` function; also curious as to how a single column can have 2x sets of `newValue/oldValue` pairs